# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException when creating a library

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting a MethodNotAllowedHttpExceptions after trying to add a helper library to laravel 4. I've created a class within app/libraries/Time.php, I have added the 'libraries' folder to the composer.json file, under the classmap.

In my global.php file I've added: app_path().'/libraries' to the addDirectories array. Afterwards I did the ./composer.phar dump-autoload.

And under my loginController is where I'm trying to make use of the class. The class in full is below this.

**app/libraries/Time.php**

```
class Time {

// convert times to user submitted time
public function set($zone)
{
    // Get user timezone from map
    $timezone = $this->get($zone);

    // set default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}

// maps the timezone the user gives
private function get($time)
{
    $zone = Array(
        'PST'  => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'MST'  => 'America/Denver',
        'CST'  => 'America/Chicago',
        'EST'  => 'America/New_York',
        'HST'  => 'America/Adak',
        'AKST' => 'America/Anchorage'
    );

    return $zone[$time];
}
}
```

I'm curious as to how I can keep the httpexception from happening and where I might be going wrong in creating this library.

UPDATE: For people wondering, the loginController is a resource controller and I'm calling the class in store() like so: Time::store($zone); It's this one line that's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's causing your problem but `set` isn't a static method in your class. Try this:

```
public static function set($zone)
{
    // Get user timezone from map
    $timezone = self::get($zone);

    // set default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}


// maps the timezone the user gives
private static function get($time)
{
    $zone = Array(
        'PST'  => 'America/Los_Angeles',
        'MST'  => 'America/Denver',
        'CST'  => 'America/Chicago',
        'EST'  => 'America/New_York',
        'HST'  => 'America/Adak',
        'AKST' => 'America/Anchorage'
    );

    return $zone[$time];
}
```

Comment: You my friend are the man. That was it. I wasn't sure how to call get without using $this->get. But both those functions not being static is what caused it. This solved it.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. You might want to look at putting stuff like this in a 'service provider'. There's a good article here: http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the link. I'll take a look at it and possibly change it around to make it work. Right now though, deadlines :P

Answer (score 0):

The error MethodNotAllowedHttpException is related to the HTTP method you are using in your route:

So if you have:

```
Route::get('posts', ...);
```

Laravel will not accept a POST to that route, you need to create a

```
Route::post('posts', ...);
```

You might also have an ambiguous route: a route wich was not supposed to be hit, is being hit instead of the other one. This could cause a route collision:

```
Route::get('{name}', ...);

Route::resource('posts', ...);
```

If you try to hit `/posts` it will hit your first get and not the resource.

Comment: @Antonio_Carlos_Ribeiro The route is a post. It's a Resource controller and it's being called in the loginController under the store() function. So it should be a post route. Also, the route works without this one line: Time::set($zone);

Comment: Edited to add another possibility.

Comment: So I did a ./artisan routes to check the routes under my app. I'm not seeing any collision but just incase, I uploaded my routes to pastebin here: http://laravel.io/bin/mJQ39. **POST portal/store** is the one that's causing the issue.